# Trouble installing C-Tools to Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

First off I have Pentaho EE version 5.0.3 and I am trying to install C-Tools. I have looked up tutorials online on how to do it and they are all the same which I follow;

When I run the command;

```
sh ctools-installer.sh -s "C:\Program Files\pentahoBA\server\biserver-ee\pentaho-solutions" -w "C:\Program Files\pentahoBA\server\biserver-ee\tomcat\webapps\pentaho"
```

I get the following response;

```
cygwin warning:
MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Program Files\pentahoBA\server\biserver-ee\pentaho-solutions
Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/pentahoBA/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions
CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
which: no zip in (/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere
CLI/Perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere 
CLI/Perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program     Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:/cygdrive/c/Tcl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware     vSphere CLI/Perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere CLI/Perl
/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program     Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:/cygdrive/c/Tcl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware     vSphere CLI/Perl/site/bin:/cygdri
ve/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware vSphere CLI/Perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program     Files/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program     Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:/cygdrive/c/Tcl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Syst
em32:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32:/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/GnuWin32/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jr
e7/bin:/cygdrive/c/plink.exe:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/
e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32:/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/GnuWin32/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Progr
am Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/plink.exe:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Network
s/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Gnu
Win32/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/plink.exe:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bi
n:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra     Networks/RuBAN/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/e/Davra Networks/RuBAN/jre7
/bin)
ERROR: Missing required 'zip' command.
```

So I try running the command;

```
sh ctools-installer.sh -s /cygdrive/c/Program Files/pentahoBA/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/ -w /cygdrive/c/Program Files/pentahoBA/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/
```

every tutorial uses `./ctools-installer.sh` but I am using Windows and when I try that command it does not work so i simply use `sh`

In the command I have provided the paths to pentaho-solutions and tomcat directories.
However after running this command I get the following;

```
ERROR: Supplied solution path is not a directory
```

As You can see I get this `ERROR` message at the bottom, saying the supplied solution path is not a directory, when it is a directory

Anyone have any idea where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive not yet used ctools installer on pentaho5 but believe someone did make it work.

Add set -x
To the top of the script and run again.

But much better solution especially on windoze is just to install from the marketplace which should already be installed! (Easy plugin download if not)

Ahh you are ee so it won't be installed.. so add it in. Marketplace is not promoted in ee weirdly

Comment: Hi Codek, thanks for the response. Just to be clear, you want me to edit the `ctools-installer.sh` file and enter `set -x` at the top of it, is it? And if I run either of the 2 commands I have it should work? If I want the marketplace I have to install the plugin, I have tried searching how to do this but I just have no luck, would you have any knowledge on this at all?

Comment: yes, set -x will add additional debugging to the script output so we can see where it is failing - possibly a missing command somewhere etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the methods described here:

http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.pt/2013/11/ctools-for-pentaho-50-is-available-cdf.html

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for the link. In the blog you say unzip the marketplace to the system, this I could not do as I did not understand this? Could you possibly elaborate on this?

Comment: Download the marketplace plugin and unzip it into the pentaho-solutions/system folder.